# Fix “AttributeError: type object has no attribute” in Python

Tags: python

This is my code and I get AttributeError. Please help!

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in get_sum_digit_powers
AttributeError: 'DigitPowers' object has no attribute 'start'
```

```
class DigitPowers():
    def __init__(self):
      pass
    def is_arm_strong(self, number):
      temp = self.number
      a=list(map(int,str(temp)))
      b=list(map(lambda x: x**5,a))
      if sum(b) == self.number:
        return True
      return False
    def get_sum_digit_powers(self, start, end):
      total = 0
      for i in range(self.start, self.end):
        if i == DigitPowers.is_arm_strong(i):
          total += i
      return total
value = DigitPowers()
print (value.get_sum_digit_powers(10000, 99999))
```

Comment: It seems you are making the assumption that parameters passed into a function i.e. start and end in `get_sum_digit_powers` are then added to the class members i.e. self.start and self.end. These are two different things there is no automatic translation from one to another. It's done manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `self`

Your code will be:

```
class DigitPowers():
    def is_arm_strong(self, number):
        temp = number
        a=list(map(int, str(temp)))
        b=list(map(lambda x: x**5, a))
        if sum(b) == number:
          return True
        return False
    def get_sum_digit_powers(self, start, end):
        total = 0
        for i in range(start, end):
            if is_arm_strong(self, i):
                total += i
        return total
value = DigitPowers()
print (value.get_sum_digit_powers(10000, 99999))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still there's an issue.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 14, in get_sum_digit_powers
TypeError: is_arm_strong() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'

Comment: @BhavikaRamesh I edited the solution. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it.

class DigitPowers():
    def __init__(self):
      pass
    def is_arm_strong(self, number):
      temp = number
      a=list(map(int,str(temp)))
      b=list(map(lambda x: x**5,a))
      if sum(b) == number:
        return True
      return False
    def get_sum_digit_powers(self, start, end):
      total = 0
      for i in range(start, end):
        if self.is_arm_strong(i):
          total += i
      return total
value = DigitPowers()
print (value.get_sum_digit_powers(10000, 99999))